# Launch tests selenium/standalone-chrome gitlab-ci

Tags: docker, selenium, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, npx

**Merry Christmas, dear smart participants**
I've this job

```
test-dev:
  stage: test
  script:
    - mkdir -p tests/js/screens/diffs
    - docker run --rm -d --name=browser_$CI_JOB_ID -p 4444:4444 -p 7900:7900 --shm-size="2g" selenium/standalone-chrome
    - npx mocha tests/js/screenshots-* --timeout 50000
    - npx playwright test tests/js/pw_*
    - php artisan test
    - docker stop browser_$CI_JOB_ID
  artifacts:
    when: always
    name: $CI_COMMIT_SHA
    untracked: true
    paths:
      - tests/js/screens
      - tests/js/report
  cache:
    when: always
    paths:
      - storage/framework
      - vendor/ #composer packages
      - node_modules
      - public
    key:
      files:
        - vendor/ #composer packages
        - composer.lock
  tags:
    - test_new_runner
```

The same job, but in progress for rebuild

```
    test-dev:
    #  allow_failure: true
      stage: test
      image: selenium/standalone-chrome
      script:
        - mkdir -p tests/js/screens/diffs
    #    - docker run --rm -d --name=browser_$CI_JOB_ID -p 4444:4444 -p 7900:7900 --shm-size="2g" selenium/standalone-chrome
        - npx mocha tests/js/screenshots-* --timeout 50000
        - npx playwright test tests/js/pw_*
        - php artisan test
    #    - docker stop browser_$CI_JOB_ID
      artifacts:
        when: always
        name: $CI_COMMIT_SHA
        untracked: true
        paths:
          - tests/js/screens
          - tests/js/report
      cache:
        when: always
        paths:
          - storage/framework
          - vendor/ #composer packages
          - node_modules
          - public
        key:
          files:
            - vendor/ #composer packages
            - composer.lock
      tags:
        - test_new_runner
```

I want to remove docker launch, because it's make a failure, but I don't undertsand how I can use this with image
But if I use image I don't have npx inside
I haven't any idea how to do this, can somebody help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make what wrote @Prabhu
But it note a last step

```
test-dev:
  stage: test
  image: docker:20.10.16  
  services:
    - docker:dind  
  script:
    - apk add --update npm
    - mkdir -p tests/js/screens/diffs
    - docker run --rm -d --name=browser_$CI_JOB_ID -p 4444:4444 -p 7900:7900 --shm-size="2g" selenium/standalone-chrome
    - npx mocha tests/js/screenshots-* --timeout 50000
    - npx playwright test tests/js/pw_*
    - php artisan test
    - docker stop browser_$CI_JOB_ID 
  artifacts:
    when: always
    name: $CI_COMMIT_SHA
    untracked: true
    paths:
      - tests/js/screens
      - tests/js/report
  cache:
    when: always
    paths:
      - storage/framework
      - vendor/ #composer packages
      - node_modules
      - public
    key:
      files:
        - vendor/ #composer packages
        - composer.lock
  tags:  
    - test_new_runner
```

After this step, you should share your docker socket in container like that

```
[[runners]]
  name = "23.01.01"
  url = ""
  id = 19
  token = ""
  token_obtained_at = 2023-01-02T05:52:07Z
  token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    MaxUploadedArchiveSize = 0
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "ruby:2.7"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache", "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"]
    shm_size = 0
```

Loock into **volumes**

Answer (score 1):

You can use base image `docker:20.10.16` then install `npx` then use `service` to run `docker dind` and then run selenium browser in your docker.

like:

```
test-dev:
  stage: test
  image: docker:20.10.16  
  services:
    - docker:dind  
  script:
    - apk add --update npm
    - mkdir -p tests/js/screens/diffs
    - docker run --rm -d --name=browser_$CI_JOB_ID -p 4444:4444 -p 7900:7900 --shm-size="2g" selenium/standalone-chrome
    - npx mocha tests/js/screenshots-* --timeout 50000
    - npx playwright test tests/js/pw_*
    - php artisan test
    - docker stop browser_$CI_JOB_ID 
  artifacts:
    when: always
    name: $CI_COMMIT_SHA
    untracked: true
    paths:
      - tests/js/screens
      - tests/js/report
  cache:
    when: always
    paths:
      - storage/framework
      - vendor/ #composer packages
      - node_modules
      - public
    key:
      files:
        - vendor/ #composer packages
        - composer.lock
  tags:  
    - test_new_runner
```

Hope this works.

Comment: It work in docker runner?

Comment: Yes. Its basically Docker Inside Docker. See this https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/#using-services-with-docker-run-docker-in-docker-side-by-side

Comment: OK: 72 MiB in 32 packages
$ docker run --rm -d --name=browser_$CI_JOB_ID -p 4444:4444 -p 7900:7900 --shm-size="2g" selenium/standalone-chrome
docker: error during connect: Post "http://docker:2375/v1.24/containers/create?name=browser_2835": dial tcp: lookup docker on 10.129.0.2:53: no such host.
See 'docker run --help'.